# Android Launcher / Home application: add automatically a Widget when a specific application is installed

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-launcher

I develop a specific Android `Launcher / Home` app for `Android 2.3`.It is based on the stock Android Launcher.
I would like to add automatically (so programmatically) a Widget on the Workspace when I have installed a specific application on the device.

I see with my `LG Optimus pad` (Android 3.1), when I install an app, there is a shorcut added automatically onto the Home Workspace

I have modified the Launcher, I successfully added a Widget automatically on the Home Workspace on application installation (broadcast receiver + find vacant cell + add Widget in database through AppWidgetManager).

I can see the Widget on the screen, but unfortunately, there is a message error : `Problem loading widget`.

By browsing with `sqlite3` in `launcher.db` the table `favorites`, I saw the inserted row for the new widget.

I don't understand why I have this error `Problem loading widget`.

Anyone had a similar problem?
Is this feature feasible?